# ubuntu 20.04 docker consul image - exited state

Tags: docker, ubuntu-12.04

followed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04 (those steps always worked for lower version of ubuntu)

> docker run -d --name=local-consul -p 8500:8500 -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul docker

(as I always do)

> docker ps

empty

> docker ps -a

**status**: "Exited (0) 4 seconds ago"

> docker logs consul-local

==> Found address '172.17.0.2' for interface 'eth0', setting bind option...
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 98: docker: not found

> docker --version

Docker version 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f3

> systemctl status docker

● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-06-01 14:30:59 EDT; 22min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 46472 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 56
     Memory: 194.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─46472 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

**Question:** 
 How to fix `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 98: docker: not found`

I've checked. I do not have this file on my local machine: `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`

Answer (score 1):

`-d` tells Docker to detach and the run the container in the background. It has nothing to do with when the container exits. The container will exit when the entrypoint process terminates. In this case, the hello-world container just prints a message and exits, so it will not continue running, detached or not.

Edit:

`docker run -d --name=local-consul -p 8500:8500 -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul docker`

If you look at the [entrypoint script](https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-consul/blob/master/0.X/docker-entrypoint.sh) for the consul image, you'll see it runs `exec "$@"`. So the `docker run` command above will attempt to run `docker` within the `consul` container. That command doesn't exist in the container, so you get `docker: not found`.

You likely just want to run the container without additional arguments:

`docker run -d --name=local-consul -p 8500:8500 -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul`

See https://hub.docker.com/_/consul

Comment: ok it was just typo... (should no be ~ docker in the end of the command, copied from another line) removing the question. thanks for reply and down-votings :)